# Mapping Problem with data loader

Tags: apex, data-loader, update, csv

I'm a beginner in salesforce and i hope this is the right place to ask.

I'm currently trying to update using data loader,
in the Mapping Step, the column header always become one,

```
ID;USERNAME;LASTNAME;FIRSTNAME;NAME;COMPANY
```

while it supposed to be,

```
ID
USERNAME
LASTNAME
FIRSTNAME
NAME
COMPANY
```

i'm using comma delimited csv file.

I was wondering if you could help me find the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Does your comma delimited file have semi-colons between the headers rather than commas as that would not help or is that just for convenience while typing? Could you maybe post a screen shot of the actual .csv file header row and maybe a row of dummy sample data so that it would be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: As Davehas suggested, please look into your CSV file. Also, post a screenshot of your file.

Comment: Thank you Dave and Shailesh, i use bellow solution to change the default list separator or manually replace all ; into , using notepad++. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set default delimiter as comma, or you may have to upgrade data loader.
If you are a windows user , here is the setting place.Region > Additional Setting > default list separator

[image]